# C++ 11 bound std::function vs storing tuple and unpacking

Tags: c++, c++11, std, variadic-templates

First off, I am still relatively new to C++11, so if I am missing anything, pardon my oversight. So what I am trying to do is basically have caller pass in a function and arbitrary # of arguments for that function, store that off and then call it asynchronously later on. And it seems there are 2 main options for this:

- use std::bind to bind a std::function to its arguments (which is obtained using variadic template) and then invoke it later
- convert the parameter pack into a tuple, store that and std::function, then unpack tuple into multiple args again and invoke function using that

Question is, is one way better than the other? Are there pro/cons/performance benefits of one over the other?

Thanks!

EDIT: as requested, here is a clarification, the first case is more early binding where I bind args to function as soon as caller passes them on and I store the bound func to be called later. the 2nd case is where I store func and args separately and invoke function with the args later on when it has to be called. So question is which is better performance/codesize/style/etc?

Comment: looks like early optimization, I would just stick with what is more convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accept a `std::function<...>` with the appropriate signature, store it to callback later. Let the caller decide how they prefer to create/populate the parameter. E.g.,

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

std::function<int(int)> stored_f;

void set_callback(std::function<int(int)> f) {
    stored_f = std::move(f);
}

void run_the_callback(int value) {
    std::cout << stored_f(value) << '\n';
}

int f(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}

int g(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    // Plain old function pointer
    set_callback(f);
    run_the_callback(1);
    // Use std::bind
    set_callback(std::bind(g, 2, std::placeholders::_1));
    run_the_callback(2);
    // Use a lambda
    set_callback([](int i){ return f(i) * g(i, i);});
    run_the_callback(3);
}
```

Best performance - if you don't absolutely require type erasure of the callback - would be to parameterize your code on functor type. E.g.:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Functor>
void do_stuff_and_callback_sometimes(Functor f) {
    std::cout << f(1) << '\n';
    // do some stuff, then
    std::cout << f(2) << '\n';
    // more work, and finally
    std::cout << f(3) << "\n\n";
}

int f(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}

int g(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    // Plain old function pointer
    do_stuff_and_callback_sometimes(f);
    // Use std::bind
    do_stuff_and_callback_sometimes(std::bind(g, 2, std::placeholders::_1));
    // Use a lambda
    do_stuff_and_callback_sometimes([](int i){ return f(i) * g(i, i);});
}
```

Avoiding type erasure is impossible in some situations, and in others will require you to jump through hoops. Whether or not it's worthwhile to do so is situational.

Comment: both this and @Nevin case may not serve the OP because the lazy-call-request may be a scenery where both function _and_ arguments are provided at request-time only.

Comment: @pepper_chico How is that a problem? I specifically engineered the example to use both an argument passed at callback invocation and argument(s) stored when the callback is set.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the feedback, but I guess my question is, is early binding better or late binding better, in terms of performance as well as code size from the resulting templates? Or is the difference insignificant here?

Comment: @user1181950 you should change your question then, I think, because you're asking about kinds of late calls that include storing arguments only.

Comment: @user1181950 Is that more what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

A third possibility is to move the responsibility of binding all the parameters to the caller, and only keep a std::function with the signature you intend to call.

For example:

```
struct Silly
{
    using Callback = std::function<void()>;

    void registerCallback(Callback cb) { callback_ = std::move(cb); }

    Callback callback_;
};
```

This way it is quite obvious that it is the caller's responsibility to deal with lifetime, value vs. reference semantics for the arguments, etc.

Comment: both this and @Casey case may not serve the OP because the lazy-call-request may be a scenery where both function and arguments are provided at request-time only.

Comment: @pepper_chico clarify?  Nevin probably means you do `silly.registerCallback( [=](){ /* code */ })` where the caller sets up the bindings.  The lack of pre-C++1y `move` capture sort of sucks here, I admit.

Comment: forget my point, I was only seeing about moving the responsability of calling (and not the responsability on binding) to the caller.